# No-op Apache mod_rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an `.htaccess` file like this:

```
RewriteCond /question2answer/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond /question2answer/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond OTHER_CONDITION_1
RewriteRule RULE_1 [L]

RewriteCond /question2answer/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond /question2answer/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond OTHER_CONDITION_2
RewriteRule RULE_2 [L]

...
```

De Morgan's laws tells me there is a better way to do this:

```
RewriteCond /question2answer/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule NO-OP [L]
RewriteCond /question2answer/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule NO-OP [L]

RewriteCond OTHER_CONDITION_1
RewriteRule RULE_1 [L]

RewriteCond OTHER_CONDITION_2
RewriteRule RULE_2 [L]    

...
```

What is the no-op rule that I can use here? And if there are many, I am seeing the one with the least performance impact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NO_OP (no operation) rule can be this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Which means if request is for a file OR if request is for a directory then don't do anything (denoted by `-` in target URI).

Comment: Reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co `The "-" rewrite target tells mod_rewrite to pass the request through unchanged. `